# Why do we say latitude and longitude instead of longitude and latitude?

Tags: history, geography

Latitude measures degree from the equator and longitude measures the degree from the prime meridian, each corresponding to the *x*-axis and *y*-axis of the world. However, normally when we are talking about axes we say the *x*-axis and then *y*-axis, so it should be longitude and latitude, but we refer to it the other way. Why is this?

Comment: Which one is more significant?

Comment: Alphabetical order?

Comment: @HotLicks They are both equally significant geographically.

Comment: If you move longitudinally around the globe, nothing happens.  When you move latitudinally the weather changes, sunrise and sunset are affected, etc.

Comment: @HotLicks we you move longitudinally the timezones change. If you're correct that would be really fun.

Comment: What do we say *criss-cross, teeter-totter. clip-clop* and not the other way around?

Comment: See Cooper & Ross's "[World Order](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/worldorder.pdf)" for some reasons.

Comment: [See: Why latitude/longitude and not the other way round?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7379/why-latitude-longitude-and-not-the-other-way-round)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Latitude is an absolute (North-South) reference frame easily determined by reference to the positions of stars and was used long ago by navigators. Longitude is a reference frame relative to an arbitrary starting line (conventionally taken as the Greenwich Meridian). Longitude could most easily be determined by comparing the time of the sun’s zenith at Greenwich with its time at the position of the navigator. This was only possible once accurate clocks had been developed. The most significant advances were made as late as the 1700s.

It therefore seems reasonable to assume that humanity was first and long ago accustomed to speaking of latitude, with later awareness of longitude. There has been no subsequent disruptive technological influence that would have changed that order.

A good account of the clocks is given by Dava Sobel in her book

> “Longitude”
>
> [Dava Sobel](https://www.worldofbooks.com/en-gb/books/dava-sobel/longitude-the-true-story-of-a-lone-genius-who-solved-the-greatest-scientific-pro/9780007718832?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIga_DzJHQ8AIVRxkGAB3K7wegEAQYAyABEgJxPfD_BwE)

It is interesting to note that techniques for measuring longitude existed long before clock technology advanced enough to be effective. The enormous difficulties of these techniques are exemplified by the efforts of Chinese astronomers in the late Middle Ages. The method involves long observation of many stars over periods of years, is esoteric, and is too long even to summarise here. It is described in:

> [Erenow](https://erenow.net/postclassical/1434-year-a-magnificent-chinese-fleet-sailed-italy-ignited-renaissance/5.php)

Comment: "Longitude", excellent book. John Harrison is one of my heroes, particularly as I live fairly near to Barrow upon Humber where he did most of his growing up, acquired his craft skills and carried out most of his early experiments.

Answer (score 1):

As tchrist said:

> What [why] do we say criss-cross, teeter-totter. clip-clop and not the other way around?

Usually, when doing this, the vowels go from the front to the back of the mouth, so a, i, e, o.

It's l*a*titude, then l*o*ngtitude.

Comment: dribs and drabs /  big and bad / bish bash bosh / juking and jiving / forgive and forget / fur and feathers / guys and gals / live and learn ... are some irreversible binomials that don't observe this claimed rule.  Note that 'latitude' and 'longitude' involve more than a mere vowel swap.